# conda install setuptools: solving environment failed CondaIndexError

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

When I want to use conda to install setuptools in ubuntu, I encountered the following:

****Solving environment: failed
CondaIndexError: Invalid index file: https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2: Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks://127.0.0.1:1080/****

How to handle this problem?

Comment: Try `conda clean -i`

Comment: I have tried, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a conda configuration file `.condarc`

```
 proxy_servers:
     http: 127.0.0.1:1080
     https: 127.0.0.1:1080
```

And set `proxy_servers` to your proxy

Read more on [conda docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html)